# kdb- ssr on a single, double quote symbol colum

Tags: kdb

I have a datasource that changed recently (same table however) and I am trying to clean up my table and having an issue with a pesky character `"` that I am trying to replace with `null`

When the table is pushed to kdb, it is a symbol column that can have a single double quote (ascii 34.) I have been running `ssr` to replace it with `null` and using `fills` to populate which it had worked at one point before the datasource change. I thought it might be a leading/trailing spaces so I checked with `trim` which seems to be fine so no rogue spaces are included.

For some reason, I am unable to perform `ssr` function on it. I'm verifying that the char is correct. I thought I had it working however my update below doesn't.

Any thoughts?  I'm assuming its my regex?

P.S. I was hoping to avoid having to use the `'int $ seg` to cast it as ascii but that is my next idea.

```
// update query does not fail but doesn't update the single, double quote in seg
t: update seg: fills `$ssr[;"\"\"";""] each string seg from t;
```

```
//verify the data types are symbols
meta t;
c            | t f a
-------------| -----
id           | s
seg          | s
```

Here is my attempt at casting the seg as string to see how to escape the quote as well as the desired goal.

```
id       seg      Displaystring    Ticker  ---->> Desired output
------------------------------------------------------
AAA  1   GOOG    "GOOG"            GOOG
AAA  2   "       ,"\""             GOOG
AAA  3   "       ,"\""             GOOG
AAA  4   "       ,"\""             GOOG
AAA  5   "       ,"\""             GOOG
AAA  6   "       ,"\""             GOOG
BBB  1   AMZN    "AMZN"            AMZN
BBB  2   "       ,"\""             AMZN
BBB  3   "       ,"\""             AMZN
CCC  1   AAPL    "AAPL"            AAPL
CCC  2   "       ,"\""             AAPL
CCC  3   "       ,"\""             AAPL
DDD  1   TSLA    ,"\""             TSLA
DDD  2   "       ,"\""             TSLA
```

Comment: Part of your issue might have been that fact that you didn't need to `ssr` the double-quote, you only need to `ssr` the single quote and kdb would have removed all of the quotes. So use `ssr[;"\"";""]` rather than `ssr[;"\"\"";""]`

Comment: Thanks Terry - I guess I had a working version of this earlier where I was importing the data as a string with double quotes at some point. My regex was off so this worked well. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the job

```
q)tab:([]id:`$raze{x,/:string 1+til y}'[("AAA ";"BBB ";"CCC ";"DDD ");6 3 3 2];seg:@[`$'14#"\"";0 6 9 12;:;`GOOG`AMZN`AAPL`TSLA])
q)tab
id    seg
----------
AAA 1 GOOG
AAA 2 "
AAA 3 "
AAA 4 "
AAA 5 "
AAA 6 "
BBB 1 AMZN
BBB 2 "
BBB 3 "
CCC 1 AAPL
CCC 2 "
CCC 3 "
DDD 1 TSLA
DDD 2 "
q)update fills?[seg=`$"\"";`;seg]from tab
id    seg
----------
AAA 1 GOOG
AAA 2 GOOG
AAA 3 GOOG
AAA 4 GOOG
AAA 5 GOOG
AAA 6 GOOG
BBB 1 AMZN
BBB 2 AMZN
BBB 3 AMZN
CCC 1 AAPL
CCC 2 AAPL
CCC 3 AAPL
DDD 1 TSLA
DDD 2 TSLA
```